# Deleting file during FTP/Database connection failed

Tags: java, apache, ftp, delete-file

my program is meant to load an image, resize it, save it, send it to FTP server and then delete resized image. Full code - [HERE](https://github.com/Nissmel/MyBREEDSViewer/tree/master/MySQL%20viewer/src/myView)

The problem I am encountering is after pressing a *finish* button from the file named *AddBreedBuilder.java*: program sends resized file to server, freeze for ~1 sec, and it is trying to remove resized file (but it is not possible).

I tried to use (at the moment this part is deleted from java file, line *165*): `File fileToDelete = new File(imgPath);
boolean success = fileToDelete.delete();` but `success` is always `false`. Only way to delete this file is to not run `sendToFTP()`.

From what I think, my program is using this file during file delete operation, so it cannot be deleted.

My question is: is it possible to delay file delete till program unfreeze?
Or maybe there is way to send resized file without saving it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From what I think, my program is using this file during file delete operation, so it cannot be deleted.

That is correct.

The reason is that your `sendToFTP` method opens the file that it is sending to the server, but it doesn't (ever) close it.  Since the file is still open, Windows won't let the app delete it

Solution: modify your `sendToFTP` method so that the `FileInputStream` is *always* closed.

Comment: You are correct! Simple `fis.close();` was enough to resolve my problem. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Beyond the questions you've asked, a few things are wrong with the code itself and it affects the answers to the questions. I'll address these later. However, to directly address your questions first:

1. Yes. You can do this by starting a new thread that handles the FTP transmission, since the transmission is initiated as the result of a GUI event, so that it doesn't freeze your application. (The event dispatch thread that handles the GUI only starts the new thread without waiting for it to finish.) In `sendToFTP()`, do:

   ```
   public static void sendToFTP(String fileName, String name) {
       Thread sender = new Thread() {
           public void run() {
               FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
               try {
                   FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(fileName));

                   client.connect("serwer1978625.home.pl");
                   client.login("nissmel@chooseyourpuppy.pl", MyBreed.getPassword());

                   client.changeWorkingDirectory("/breeds");
                   client.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);

                   client.storeFile(name, fis);
                   // client.rename(fileName, name); // not necessary
                   client.logout();
                   // At this point you must close the FileInputStream, since that is what is using the file, as you noticed.
                   fis.close();
                   // TODO: your code to delete the file comes in here, if everything goes well
                   // Alternatively, you could do these in the finally block to run irrespective of how the above code executes
               }
               catch (IOException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
               finally {
                   try {
                       client.disconnect();
                   }
                   catch (Exception e) {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                   }
               }
           }

       };
            // the event dispatch thread only starts the sender thread and exits this function,
       // hence no freezing occurs
       sender.start();
   }
   ```

   Then in the calling function, `buildAdd()`

   ```
   // ...
   sendToFTP(imgPath, userBreedInfo[0] + ".jpg");
   // ...
   ```
2. You can definitely send the file (more precisely, the file contents) without having to produce the file at all. You can instead supply the `BufferedImage` directly to the `sendToFTP()` method, and then transform that to the required `InputStream` for `client.storeFile()`. In this case you don't even need to store the file at all in the first place if you don't need it on the local machine.

   ```
   public static void sendToFTP(BufferedImage bimage, String name) {
         // ... some code
         // Here we need an input stream for storeFile(), so we get that from an output stream
         // produced in turn by the buffered image
         ByteArrayOutputStream outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
         ImageIO.write(bimage, "png", outStream);
         InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(outStream.toByteArray());
         // ... some code
         client.storeFile(name, is);
         // ... rest of code
   }
   ```

Then in the calling function, `buildAdd()`

```
    // ...
    sendToFTP(bimage, userBreedInfo[0] + ".jpg");
    // ...
```

Notice the change in the signature of the second version of `sendToFTP()`. You could play with this idea in a different way, and rather replace the file writing call in `buildAdd()` with this `InputStream`, and then pass the stream to `sendToFTP()`.

**Note**
You can use the try-with-resources idiom for ensuring the streams used above are automatically closed: see
[here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) for example.

**Other issues addressed:**

1. No need to rename the file after storing on the FTP endpoint: just
   use the final name the first time.
2. Be sure to close the streams. That's what caused the error you reported.
3. In the better case, no need to create a file on the local system in the first place (i.e. within `buildAdd()`).

Comment: The `name` variable should not change within the new lambda scope defined as the body of the `Thread` instantiator. So create another local variable, maybe `String outFileName = name + ".jpg"`. Then use `client.storeFile(outFileName, fis)` instead. 

Better still, pass the exact name you want to `sendToFTP()` (including the `.jpg` extension, so you just use `name` exactly as-is in  `client.storeFile(name, fis)`

Comment: I have edited the answer to reflect the latter approach.